# Subscription Admin in Azure CSP subscription

Tags: azure, azure-automation

Is it possible to become Subscription Co-Admin in CSP subscription? My current role is Owner.

I have problem with some runbooks in RunAs Automation Account. Runbook fails to execute commands with Forbiden Error. I think that is because, Automation Account was created with account which is not Co-Admin.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Azure CSP subscriptions have the limitation that they do not allow to manage add users as Co-Administrators from the Azure Portal. If not mistaken there is a process that can be done from the Azure Partner Center

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/how-to--associate-a-partner-center-account-with-an-active-azure-subscrption-account

Hope this is of help to you!